# XMLHttpRequest() .responseText not returning full data

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, qml, responsetext

I am using XMLHttpRequest() to get xml data from a webpage and use it in a XmlListModel. The problem that I got seems to be that XmlListModel only gets a small portion of the data as .responseText using `console.log(httpReq.responseText)` only gives me a partial xml data around 20% of what's inside the xml.

The other issue is that XmlListModel is always behind one call, when I first call the function it says fullscreen is undefined but when I call it again it's fine. BUT this function needs to be called ever 1 second to get updated data as the xml file is always changing but only ever second call gives me right data.

The function looks like this:

```
XmlListModel{
    id: xmlModel
    query: "/root"
    XmlRole{ name: "fullscreen"; query: "fullscreen/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "volume"; query: "volume/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "random"; query: "random/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "state"; query: "state/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "loop"; query: "loop/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "repeat"; query: "repeat/string()"}
}

function getVLCstatus()
{
    var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url = "http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/requests/status.xml";

    httpReq.open("GET", url, true);
    // Send the proper header information along with the request
    httpReq.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Qt.btoa(username + ":" + password));
    httpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',  'text/xml');
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(httpReq.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        {
            if(httpReq.status == 200)
            {
                xmlModel.xml = httpReq.responseText
                console.log(xmlModel.get(0).fullscreen)
            }
        }
    }
    httpReq.send();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Some browsers doesn't have the constants like `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`. Use the numeric value:

```
if(httpReq.readyState === 4)
```

Comment: No if you look if cut off a part of the xml here as well:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>

<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
<aspectratio>default</aspectratio>
<audiodelay>0</audiodelay>
<apiversion>3</apiversion>
<currentplid>16</currentplid>
<time>1</time>
<volume>248</volume>
<len`